# Can't start intent service in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can't start intent service

I am writing code for synch data for every 10 minute whenapp is in forground,background or sleep . I had write weakfulintentservice for it calling it from Alaramreceiver but AppService doesn't get call.

AppService

```
 public class AppService : WakefulIntentService
{
    public AppService() : base("AppService")
    {

    }

    protected override void DoWakefulWork(Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "In service", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        Log.Info("AppService", "I'm awake! I'm awake!");
    }
}
```

WeakFulIntentService

```
abstract public class WakefulIntentService : IntentService
{
    abstract protected void DoWakefulWork(Intent intent);
    public static string NAME = "com.jondouglas.wakeful.WakefulIntentService";
    public static string LAST_ALARM = "lastAlarm";
    private static volatile PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic = null;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock GetLock(Context context)
    {
        if (lockStatic == null)
        {
            PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);

            lockStatic = manager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, NAME);
            lockStatic.SetReferenceCounted(true);
        }
        return (lockStatic);
    }

    public static void SendWakefulWork(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        GetLock(context.ApplicationContext); //Possibly use of acquire here
        context.StartService(intent);
    }

    public static void SendWakefulWork(Context context, Type classService)
    {
        SendWakefulWork(context, new Intent(context, classService));
    }

    public static void ScheduleAlarms(IAlarmListener alarmListener, Context context)
    {
        ScheduleAlarms(alarmListener, context, true);
    }

    public static void ScheduleAlarms(IAlarmListener alarmListener, Context context, bool force)
    {
        ISharedPreferences preferences = context.GetSharedPreferences(NAME, 0);
        long lastAlarm = preferences.GetLong(LAST_ALARM, 0);

        if (lastAlarm == 0 || force ||
            (DateTime.Now.Millisecond > lastAlarm &&
             DateTime.Now.Millisecond - lastAlarm > alarmListener.GetMaxAge()))
        {
            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmListener.ScheduleAlarms(manager, pendingIntent, context);
        }
    }

    public static void CancelAlarms(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof (AlarmReceiver));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        manager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
        context.GetSharedPreferences(NAME, 0).Edit().Remove(LAST_ALARM).Commit();
    }

    public WakefulIntentService(string name) : base(name)
    {
        SetIntentRedelivery(true);
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = GetLock(this.ApplicationContext);

        if (!lockStatic.IsHeld || (flags & StartCommandFlags.Redelivery) != 0)
        {
            wakeLock.Acquire();
        }
        return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        return (StartCommandResult.RedeliverIntent);
    }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            DoWakefulWork(intent);
        }
        finally
        {
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = GetLock(this.ApplicationContext);

            if (wakeLock.IsHeld)
            {
                try
                {
                    wakeLock.Release();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(Class.SimpleName, "Exception when releasing wakelock", ex);
                    //Log exception when releasing wakelock
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IAlarmListener
    {
        void ScheduleAlarms(AlarmManager manager, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Context context);
        void SendWakefulWork(Context context);
        long GetMaxAge();
    }
```

**CallToAppService**

```
      public void SendWakefulWork(Context context)
    {
        WakefulIntentService.SendWakefulWork(context, typeof(AppService));
    }
```

The call for AppService  context.StartService(intent); from weakfulintentservice execute perfectly
    but AppService cant start In xamarin.android.
Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: It works perfectly with native android with java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The call for AppService context.StartService(intent); from weakfulintentservice execute perfectly but AppService cant start In xamarin.android.

You can refer to [Started Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_1_-_started_services/), in your Xamarin.Android code where you want to start your `AppService`, you can code as simply as this:

```
StartService (new Intent (this, typeof(AppService)));
```

If you want to start a service with an intent filter, you can refer to [this part](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_1_-_started_services/#Starting_a_Service_With_an_Intent_Filter).

Also you may refer to the case I answered several days ago: [Xamarin Android : Change UI TextView text from Service or Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409563/xamarin-android-change-ui-textview-text-from-service-or-receiver/46439815#46439815).

Comment: @SwapnilWakchaure, did you add attribute `[Service]` at the top of your `AppService` ?

Comment: @SwapnilWakchaure, I tested the [demo](https://github.com/JonDouglas/xamarin-android-tutorials/tree/master/Wakeful/WakefulIntentService),works fine....

Comment: issue solved by removing name attribute from  [Service] . Thanks Grace