# Xamarin custom BroadcastReceiver event is always null even though I add the event handler

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am creating an Android App using Xamarin. Basically the app detect the incoming SMS and if the sender is a specific number the GUI get updated. I have created a class that inherits BroadcastReceiver and at the proper conditions Raises the event  but the event is always null even though I subscribe with a method that when is susbcribed in a button click event works correctly (I create an instance of this class in MainActivity and add the EventHandler in OnCreate method) After the research it seems a bit strange that the code EventHandler is null... What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

BroadcastReceiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true, Enabled = true)]

[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"}, Priority =(int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]

public class NewSMSReceived : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public event EventHandler SMSArrived;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (Android.Provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents.SmsReceivedAction.Equals(intent.Action))
        {

            var info_Intent = intent.Extras;

            if (info_Intent != null)
            {
                Java.Lang.Object[] pdus = (Java.Lang.Object[]) info_Intent.Get("pdus");

                var msg = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

                var msg_from = msg.DisplayOriginatingAddress;

                if (msg_from == "xxxxxxxxxx")
                {

                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "New message from Weather Station", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    SMSArrived?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private NewSMSReceived SMSNotificator = new NewSMSReceived();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        this.SMSNotificator.SMSArrived += new EventHandler(this.showNewData);
    }

    private void showNewData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a pure guess, but doesn't the app require some kind of permission when reading SMS?

Comment: Sure, that part of program is working fine, I can read and send SMS from app after I added the permissions to manifest and the user (Actually Me) confirm these permissions.

Comment: You should be using a *bound service* as the NewSMSReceived class that you creating in that activity is not the NewSMSReceived service subclass that the Android OS is creating upon receipt of the broadcast intent  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/bound-services

Comment: Is this the reason why the event is always null?

Comment: @JonadriBundo Yes, they are not the same instance

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that helped me reach to a solution. After some other research I made it worked registering instance SMSNotificator on "OnResume" and unregistering it at "OnPause". Below I will post the code

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using the answer of question [Xamarin Android : Change UI TextView text from Service or Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409563/xamarin-android-change-ui-textview-text-from-service-or-receiver) and the comment of @SushiHangover helped me realize the problem. Registering the Instance of NewSMSReceived using OnResume method and unregistering it using OnPause method solved the problem (at the first try I did non delete the property IntentFilter of NewSMSReceived and it did not worked). Code modifications are as follows:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true, Enabled = true)]
public class NewSMSReceived : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public event EventHandler SMSArrived;
    //nothing changes
```

Code in MainActivity (Instance is initialized only once and event is subscribed at "OnCreate" method)

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var NewSMS = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

        RegisterReceiver(this.SMSNotificator, NewSMS);


    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

        UnregisterReceiver(this.SMSNotificator);

    }
```